# Import geoviews in Anaconda

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, geoviews

I am trying to install the geoviews module. I installed it successfully but when I am trying to import it in my code I have this message:

`No module named 'channels`

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: this shouldn't happen and could be a bug in the geoviews conda spec. can you post the exact command you ran to install geoviews as well as the import command which throws this error? Also, can you post the result of `conda list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I write in my Anaconda PowerShell and it works !

```
conda install -c conda-forge geoviews
```

Answer (score 0):

Try install the `channels` module via the command:

```
pip install channels
```

or

```
python -m pip install -U channel
```